# eclipse scala IDE doc - automatic insert of @param and @author tags

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Hi I am looking how to add such tags automatically when i type /** on any class or methods. for example in java you automatically gets following when you type /** and press enter on method.

```
   /**
     * 
     * @param str
     */
    public static void main(String[] str){}
```

This doesn't happen with scala defs.

```
 /**
   * 
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
```

How do i achieve same effect in scala as java doc. I tried playing with template under Scala -> Editor -> Templates but that doesn't automatically adds anything when i type /** and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following -

Write `@a` Enter `ctrl+spacebar`.

```
 /**
 *@author AUTHOR_NAME
 */
```

OR

`Windows -> Preferences -> Scala -> Implicits`

You'll find

`More options for highlighting for implicit conversations on the Text Editors/Annotations preference page`.

Comment: thanks but i know that one. I am looking for exact equivalent of java ide though where i dont have to type anything. even for this I still have to add all other tags (param, return) to scala templates to be able to use this way. but anyway i'm not looking to go that route

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported. There is an open ticket for it: [#1001385](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001385-auto-completion-of-scaladoc-annotations#/activity/ticket:)

While we don't have the time to implement this feature by ourselves, we would be happy to support anyone who wants to implement it by themselves.

Comment: what is LOE for first timer to contribute ?  Can someone point me how to add this feature? I know git, java, maven stack and some scala since I just started.

Comment: Asking on the [mailing lists](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/scala-ide-dev) is a good start.